# How to ensure fluency in a frequently refreshed TableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

there has a tableView Who refreshed every 0.5 seconds;

i uesd `tableView reloadData` or `reloadSections: withRowAnimation:`

Both of them cause FPS decrease

what can i do for it?

the tableView has new data every 0.5 seconds

and need display new data immediately

## code:

```
- (void)registerTableViewCells {
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell1 class] forCellReuseIdentifier: UITableViewCell1Identifier];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell2 class] forCellReuseIdentifier: UITableViewCell2Identifier];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell3 class] forCellReuseIdentifier: UITableViewCell3Identifier];
}

- (void)makeUpDisplaySource {
    NSMutableArray *arrM = [NSMutableArray array];
    [arrM addObject:@[UITableViewCell1Identifier, @(60), @(1)]];
    [arrM addObject:@[UITableViewCell2Identifier, @(55), @(10)]];
    [arrM addObject:@[UITableViewCell3Identifier, @(30), @(10+_fortySeat*30)]];
    // _fortySeat is  boolValue
    self.displaySource = arrM;
}
```

## tableView delegate

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSArray *dataArr = self.displaySource[indexPath.section];
    NSString *identifier = dataArr[0];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ([NSStringFromClass(cell.class) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCell1"]) {
        UITableViewCell1 *newcell = (UITableViewCell1 *)cell;
        [newcell  updatCellUI];
    }
    else if ([NSStringFromClass(cell.class) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCell2"]) {
        UITableViewCell2 *newcell = (UITableViewCell2 *)cell;
        [newcell updatCellUIBuy: model1 sell: model2];
    }
    else if ([NSStringFromClass(cell.class) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCell3"]){
        cell.backgroundColor = GL_CELL_BACKGROUD_COLOR;
        [cell addSubview:self.someView];// someView is a lazy property
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use only reloadsections insted of reload full table data

Comment: 1) Try to optimize your code. 
2) Avoid reuse table each 0.5 sec.
3) If you have some updating label in the cell,- do it inside that cell.
4) need more information about data what you show (images/text/etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using reusable cells, of course, reload the data every 0.5 seconds may cause FPS problems beacause you'll reload the data of all the cells present in your TableView.

Also even if you are reloading data with `reloadSections:`, you'll have problems if you are reloading all the modified cells. Even those who are not visible. -- And this may cause problems.

---

In that case I suggest you to :

1. Use : `[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CellID"];`

   This will register your tableView under a xib file and the cells under an ID.
2. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` load your cell using this ID :
   `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellID"];`

   Using reusable cells you will increase the speed of loading your TableView and it may help you while refreshing it.

---

If you are already using reusable cells I suggest you to let people know it in your question.
Even if your are using reusable cells you could simply decrease a bit the interval time between 2 reloads if you still have problems with FPS.

I might not have completly understood your question and I might be wrong on certains points. Of course do not hesitate to let me know/edit my answer, I will apreciate it.

Comment: I wich you'll find out, but maybe just as @biloshkurskyi-ss said try to avoid reloading your table each 0.5 seconds, moreover if you have lots of data to reload.